# How to use BeginSignIn or how to login to Skype for Business for making automatic phone call using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

I have found [THIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lync/desktop/how-to-sign-a-user-in-to-lync) link which shows how to login to Skype/Lynk using C#. I have also found a sample Visual Studio Solution under **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\samples\AudioVideoConversation\AudioVideoConversation.sln** which you will get when you install Lynk 2013 SDK. After successfully building this project in Visual Studio you can make phone calls from Skype for Business.

I am developing a PowerShell Script to make automatic phone calls by translating the code in this .Net project to PowerShell, However, not sure how to successfully translate this into PowerShell. I am stuck at first step, to sign in to Lynk through PowerShell Code.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office 2013\LyncSDK\Assemblies\Desktop\Microsoft.Lync.Model.dll"

$LC = [Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient]::GetClient()

$obj = [System.Object]::new()
$iP = [System.IntPtr]::new(1)
$acb = [System.AsyncCallback]::new($obj,$iP)

$LC.BeginSignIn("testuser@contoso.com","contoso\sshahoo",'P@ssw0rd', $acb, $obj)
```

Can someone please share how to connect to Skype for Business using PowerShell and make a Phone call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and coding I am now able to login to Skype for Business through a button click event and start a phone call. Below is the code if anyone is interested:

```
    private void btnCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if this client is in UISuppressionMode...
        if (client.InSuppressedMode && client.State == ClientState.Uninitialized)
        {
            //...need to initialize it
            try
            {
                client.BeginInitialize(this.ClientInitialized, null);
            }
            catch (LyncClientException lyncClientException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lyncClientException);
            }
            catch (SystemException systemException)
            {
                if (LyncModelExceptionHelper.IsLyncException(systemException))
                {
                    // Log the exception thrown by the Lync Model API.
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + systemException);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Rethrow the SystemException which did not come from the Lync Model API.
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        else //not in UI Suppression, so the client was already initialized
        {
            //registers for conversation related events
            //these events will occur when new conversations are created (incoming/outgoing) and removed
            //client.ConversationManager.ConversationAdded += ConversationManager_ConversationAdded;
            //client.ConversationManager.ConversationRemoved += ConversationManager_ConversationRemoved;

            //sign-in or contact selection
            SignInToLync();
        }
        SendLyncCall("+6512345678", "Hello, I am calling regarding an open ticket");
    }

    LyncClient client = LyncClient.GetClient();
    private void SignInToLync()
    {
        try
        {
            client.BeginSignIn("abc@contoso.com", "abc@contoso.com", "Pass@1234", HandleEndSignIn, null);
        }
        catch (LyncClientException lyncClientException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lyncClientException);
        }
        catch (SystemException systemException)
        {
            if (LyncModelExceptionHelper.IsLyncException(systemException))
            {
                // Log the exception thrown by the Lync Model API.
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + systemException); 
            }
            else
            {
                // Rethrow the SystemException which did not come from the Lync Model API.
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```